# Changing variable to elif within if statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm trying to figure out how to make this work:

```
if variable == "yes":
    variable = "no"
elif variable == "no:
```

What I want to happen is for the program to start running the elif statement after variable has been changed to match it. How should I go about that?

Comment: You can't, the whole point of `elif`s is their independence.

Comment: Do you want the code in your `elif` block to only run if `variable` has been changed from `"yes"` to `"no"` or also if it has been `"no"` to begin with?

Answer (score 6):

You can't; not with an `if..elif` structure. Python picks the *first* condition that matches and will disregard the rest, no matter what changes you make in the block of code that was run. In other words, in a series of `if...elif...elif` blocks, only *one* will ever be picked.

You'd have to use *separate* `if` blocks:

```
if variable == 'yes':
    variable = 'no'

if variable == 'no':
    # ...
```

Separate `if` statement groups are independent.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif variable == "no:
```

or

```
else
```

These are only checked if the `if` is evaluated `False`.

if the `if` clause is true, `else` or `elif` is discarded immediately.

So, one liner for your question,

NO, you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to happen is for the program to start running the elif statement after variable has been changed to match it. How should I go about that?

Not much we can understand from that, But something I got to know is.
You need to run a function or code, only after occur of elif statement ie, if variable is 'no'
You can use `while` statement

```
while variable is 'yes':
   #continue or do something
   if someoccurances:
       variable = 'no'
       #break or call a function that elif does
#if break, Do your elif here!
if variable is 'no':
    #Do your function here!
```